# sort array by key value and display the key

Tags: php, arrays

I have this Array

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 61
            [testo] => articolo di maggio
            [data] => 2013-05-03
            [orario] => 00:00:00
            [nome_files] => fabmad_1920x1200.jpg
            [pubblicato] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 58
            [testo] => 
            [data] => 2013-06-03
            [orario] => 00:00:00
            [nome_files] => 20130603100647_da_installare.rtf
            [pubblicato] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 59
            [testo] => Demo
            [data] => 2013-06-03
            [orario] => 00:00:00
            [nome_files] => eye_drops_water_2.jpg
            [pubblicato] => 1
        )


)
```

I want to sort it by "data".
I want to display the "data" and for each data the elements...

Comment: How are you populating the array? From a database?

Comment: yes.from a table created on wordpress installation

Answer (score 0):

Try the ksort function or the array-multisort

Check the php documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php